# Slash in regular expression in Golang

Tags: regex, go, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-greedy

I have two links:

```
1: /aaa/bbbb/ccccc.htm
2: /xxx/yyy.htm
```

What regex is able to match the second link?

I have tried:

```
^\/.*\/.*[^\/].*
```

But, it match all of them.

Comment: `^/[^/]+/[^/]+$` , start with `/`, then `non /` string,  a `/`, end with `non /` string

Comment: `^(?:\/\w+){2}\.htm` This should be what you are looking for!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing that we might want to pass both URLs, which in that case we would start with:

```
(\/[a-z]+)?(?:\.htm)?
```

We can then add more boundaries, if you wish.

#### RegEx

If this wasn't your desired expression, you can modify/change your expressions in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/TmX7F7/2).

[image]

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

#### JavaScript Group Breakup

```js
const regex = /((\/[a-z]+)?(?:\.htm)?)/gm;
const str = `/aaa/bbbb/ccccc.htm
/xxx/yyy.htm`;
const subst = `Group #1: $1\nGroup #2: $2\n`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```

---

If you only wish to pass the second URL and fail the first one, you can simply add some boundaries to your expression, maybe something similar to [this](https://regex101.com/r/x9xH86/2) would work:

```
^\/[a-z]+\/[a-z]+.htm$
```

[image]

Comment: for Go questions, don't forget to change regex101 to use the RE2 engine instead of PCRE. I took the liberty to update the links.